# How to use "Context" of one class into another class - Android

Tags: java, android, class, android-context

I am using a context in one class. How can i refer the same context while initiating it in another class?

MyHttpClient.java

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {


    final Context contextkey;

    public MyHttpClient(Context contextkeystore) {
        this.contextkey = contextkeystore;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
        // to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = contextkey.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mykeystore);
            try {
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
                // Also provide the password of the keystore
                trusted.load(in, "mysecret".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
            // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
            // for the verification of the server certificate.
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
            // Hostname verification from certificate
            // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To use in another class :

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext()); ??
```

Here "getApplicationContext" won't work and shown an error

Comment: Where are you calling getApplicationContext() from? Can you post the error thrown on getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: I am calling it in another class inside "DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());"

Comment: Does this class extend Activity? Can you post the error log on getApplicationContext() please?

Comment: No this class is not an activity class. There is no error but it shows red underline and asks me to create method "getApplicationContext()"

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to get the Application Context is follows

```
package com.example.testactivity;

        public class App extends Application {
        public static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
                    super.onCreate();
                    context=getApplicationContext();
                           }
    public static Context getcontext(){
     return context;
     }

   }
```

and in the manifest file 
add the line in the application tag

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.testactivity.App" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Now you will the context of the application any where in the app

just call

```
App.getcontext();
```

Njoy :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a valid context to extend DefaultHttpClient with SSL.

It seems that the class calling your MyHttpClient constructor does not have a valid Context to pass to the HttpClient.

You should pass a context through that class into your client:

- Start where your app launches (Launcher Activity, Service, etc...)
- Create your Class (you haven't given us a name), passing getApplicationContext, or an activity cast (this), as a parameter.
- Have your Class create MyHttpClient, passing said context to the constructor.

It goes:

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
      private Foo myfoo;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
      {
             myfoo = new Foo(this); //Or myFoo = new Foo(getApplicationContext());   
      }
}

public class Foo
{
    private Context mycontext;
    private MyHttpClient myclient;

    public Foo(Context ctx)
    {
        mycontext = ctx;//No need to save the context if you aren't reusing it after this.
        myclient = new MyHttpClient(mycontext); 
    }
}
```